# creating hierarchichal XML structure dynamically

Tags: .net, xml, c#-2.0, xmldocument, xmlnode

I am creating an XML as shown by below code

```
public class Group
{
[XmlElement(typeof(Manager))]
public Employee [] Staff;

[XmlElement (typeof(int)),
XmlElement (typeof(string)),
XmlElement (typeof(DateTime))]
public ArrayList ExtraInfo;
}

public class Employee
{
public string Name;
}

public class Manager:Employee
{
public int Level;
}

public class Run 
{
public static void Main()
{
  Run test = new Run();
  test.SerializeObject("TypeEx.xml");
}

public void SerializeObject(string filename)
{
     // Create an XmlSerializer instance.
  XmlSerializer xSer = 
  new XmlSerializer(typeof(Group));

  // Create object and serialize it.
  Group myGroup = new Group();

  Manager e1 = new Manager();
  e1.Name = "Manager1";
  Manager m1 =  new Manager();
  m1.Name = "Manager2";
  m1.Level = 4;

  Employee[] emps = {e1, m1};
  myGroup.Staff = emps;

  myGroup.ExtraInfo = new ArrayList();
  myGroup.ExtraInfo.Add(".NET");
  myGroup.ExtraInfo.Add(42);
  myGroup.ExtraInfo.Add(new DateTime(2001,1,1));

  TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filename);
  xSer.Serialize(writer, myGroup);
  writer.Close();
  }
  }
```

shared at "http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.type(v=vs.80).aspx". In this scenario I am adding 2 managers in employee which are "e1" and "m1". But if I have to add 5 managers in a loop I updated this code as below:
Manager[] a = new Manager[5];

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        a[i] = new Manager();
        a[i].Name = "temp" + i;
        a[i].Level = i;
    }
    Employee[] empss = new Employee[5];

    for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++)
    {
        empss[k] = new Employee();
        myGroup.Staff = empss[k]; // line25
    }
```

but it is giving me following error: "Cannot implicitly convert type 'Employee' to 'Employee[]'" at line25. Can anybody suggest me how to correct it?

Comment: It looks like you've got every name twice - how are you meant to know at what point to stop nesting?

Comment: No I am not getting it twice but intentionally I am doing so.

Comment: see my edit. Hope now u can understand why I am repeating structure. No of structures added depends upon number of *.xml files at  c:\\temp\\LocalPath\\FAMILY_NAME\\RELEASE_TYPE\\.

Comment: But the loop you've got in code *only* uses `xmlTagNameList` and `tagNames`. How does that correspond to the directory structure? Your question is unclear.

Comment: ok take as. I have a file Release.xml at c:\temp\LocalPath\FAMILY_NAME\PACKAGE_NAME\RELEASE_TYPE\Release.xml and after c:\temp\LocalPath\ string each folder name will be my XML tag name and at point I am getting a file I am setting it as current XMl tag's innerText. Is it clear now?